# Relationship model between users, companies and introductions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

Apologies for the newbie question but I am completely stumped on this one.

I have two models, user and company, and I am trying to establish a "request_introduction" relationship between them.

A user can have one intro_request with many companies while a company can have one intro_request from many users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"A user can have one intro_request with many companies"* -- Huh? Are you saying that **one** request is for **many** companies? It sounds more likely that a user should have many intro_requests, where each is for one company. Either that, or they can only have one request for one company.

Comment: I personally find it helpful to quickly sketch out the relationship on paper to visualise it.

Comment: @TomLord, sorry yes what I meant to say is that a user can have many intro_requests, one to each company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brian,
It sounds like you want to do many-to-many relationship between 'user' and 'company'.  You can set this by creating a :through association.

It should something similar to this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :introductions
  has_many :customers, through: :introductions
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :customers
end

class Introduction < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :customers, through: :users
end
```

Here is a link to the rails guide: (section 2.4) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thank you! Been stuck on this for ages. I find my biggest problem is phrasing the question correctly into Google.